# Loading twitter bootstrap using browserify

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, browserify

How do I use Twitter bootstrap in browserify?
I installed bootstrap-browserify, and tried using this in my code

Later in my code, I have some code trying to patch the modal dialog function of bootstrap, but it throws an error.

This is how my code looks like:

```
var bootstrap = require('bootstrap-browserify');

$(document).ready(function () {

    $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function () {
        var that = this;
        $(document).on('focusin.modal', function (e) {
            if ($(e.target).hasClass('select2-input')) {
                return true;
            }

            if (that.$element[0] !== e.target && !that.$element.has(e.target).length) {
                that.$element.focus();
            }
        });
    };
}
```

I am completely new to browserify and I am using it for the first time. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error is it throwing? Is it an error in the browser or in Node?

Answer (score 1):

First you'll have to install Bootstrap, jQuery, and [browserify-shim](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim). I prefer to install these with Bower (because of the flat dependency structure) but you could also use NPM. This is the browserify-shim section of my `package.json` config:

```
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "browserify-shim"
    ]   
  },  
  "browser": {
    "jquery": "./bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "bootstrap": "./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  },  
  "browserify-shim": {
    "jquery": "$",
    "bootstrap": {
      "depends": [
        "jquery: jQuery"
      ]   
    }   
  },
```

The way I prefer to install Bootstrap (and its dependency jQuery) is to install these to the global scope. Therefore, somewhere in my code that will be "browserified" I'll put the following:

```
$ = jQuery = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap');
```

Note that I'm not using `var` here. This means that `$`, `jQuery`, and the necessary Bootstrap javascript will be available on the `window` object.

Comment: When I try using this, I get unexpected token "/" in package.json error

Comment: @HorribleGuy that's most likely a typo in your `package.json` file, maybe in a different section.

Comment: it was, but I have one more problem, have asked a question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36939784/using-jquery-plugin-in-browserify-along-with-angular, can you plz look at it?

Answer (score -3):

There's no real need to use browserify with bootstrap.  A typical approach would be to include bootstrap.js with a `<script>` tag above the bundle that browserify creates, and then just use it normally without needing a `require()` statement. If you want to avoid the extra HTTP request, you can just concatenate bootstrap with your custom browserify bundle using [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) or something similar.

Since Bootstrap depends on JQuery, you can also do something like combine JQuery and Bootstrap  into a vendor.js, and include that above the custom bundle that browserify makes.

Comment: but we want jquery to be included through browserify!

Comment: This is not an answer to the question