# using jquery plugin in browserify along with angular

Tags: browserify, browserify-shim

I am trying to use a tooltip plugin called [tipso](http://tipso.object505.com/). And I am using angular along with browserify as my dependency manager.

I have everything working out for me except for this plugin. Every little thing is little harder in browserify but this one seems to be turning into a nightmare.

I have followed the documentation of tipso which is pretty simple. But when I run the app, I keep getting an error message stating that `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tipso is not a function` in the chrome console.

This is my broserify-shim config

```
   "browserify-shim": {
   "jquery": "$",
   "bootstrap": {
     "depends": [
       "jquery"
     ]
   },
   "tipso": {
       "depends": [
           "bootstrap"
       ]
    }
  }
```

I have required tipso

```
var tipso = require('tipso');
```

This is how I have initialized tipso

```
//runs when DOM is completely loaded
angular.element(document).ready(function ($http, $rootScope) {    
    $('.tipso').tipso();
});
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out, I hope this helps someone.

1. The trick is to expose jQuery in the global scope (I know I am not supposed to do this and the alternative for this is to expose it wherever I want the plugin to work).

   ```
   global.$ = global.jQuery = require('jquery');
   ```
2. Once that is done, we'll make an Angular directive

   ```
   rootModule.directive('cooltip', function () {
     return {
         restrict: 'A',
         link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
             $(element).tipso({
                 position: 'right',
                 delay: 600
           });
         }
      };
   });
   ```
3. Use this directive to use apply the jQuery plugin's properties on an element in html

   ```
   <button cooltip class="btn"> Hover over me </button>
   ```

Depending on the jQuery plugin and it;s funtionality decide on the directive type (Element, Attribute, Comment etc).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using it like `$(...).tipso` per the error, and you're requiring jQuery as `$` per your Browserify Shim config, I'm assuming Tipso is a jQuery plugin. You need to specify that this it depends on jQuery, like so:

```
 "browserify-shim": {
   "jquery": "$",
   "bootstrap": {
     "depends": [
       "jquery"
     ]
   },
   "tipso": {
       "depends": [
           "jquery",
           "bootstrap"
       ],
    "exports": "$.fn.tipso"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Same thing, as mentioned in the question, the global namespace is not polluted, I checked by typing in $ in chrome console.

Comment: Try explicitly exporting the plugin per my update. I have one more idea if that doesn't work. Sometimes these are a little touchy which is a terrible way to think as a programmer but I don't know Browserify Shim yet well enough to know a better solution offhand :).

Comment: If you want to pollute your global namespace you need to do that explicitly in your build, like `window.$ = require('jquery'); require('tipso');`

Comment: I am totally surprised and slightly scared that about the no of views a question gets on stack overflow these days...